# Developer Dashboard : SpRequest Allocation

Tags: 2010, performance, developer

I am working on a Performance project . In the developer dashboard , what is the significance of SPRequest Allocations ? I see around 20 SPsite and Spweb objects being displayed onto the site .

Answer (score 0):

Displays SP Request allocations and can be used to check whether or not SPRequest objects are properly set to dispose.

You can also get the details of each requests.

Comment: Does it show all the requests used in your site ? OR only requests/objects which are not disposed properly ?

Comment: All, in details section you can check which are disposed or not.